# Photos framework error when compiled in Xcode 11.1

Tags: objective-c, photo

I have updated my xcode 10.3 to latest version xcode11.1 and i have added the photos framework in my project.When i run my project i get "Photos requires C++11 or later" error in PHImageManager.h class.Below i have mentioned the error.

Error:
1./Applications/xcode11/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Photos.framework/Headers/PHImageManager.h:18:2: "Photos requires C++11 or later"
2./Applications/xcode11/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Photos.framework/Headers/PHImageManager.h:21:47: Expected identifier or '{'

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Build Settings, then change `C++ Language Dialect` to `GNU++11 [-std=gnu++11]` worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Can't find this setting. Where is it?

Comment: added an image above

Comment: Thanks for the update. So it is a project specific setting. Thought it was a generell one. Because I use Xamarin I can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me.U need to edit PHImagemanager.h file  https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6716#issuecomment-534034433

Comment: Edit a file within `/Applications`?

Comment: @trojanfoe
Full path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Photos.framework/Headers/PHImageManager.h 

.There u need to change this `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIImageOrientation);` to that  `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIImageOrientation){};`